# P-value approximation from an underlying unknown distribution

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, bioinformatics, biostatistics, fourier-transform

I am calculating a certain statistic(relative entropy) of a certain sequence alignment over DNA sequences. The statistic has a certain distribution in the entire genome of which I only have 1000 sequences of length 1000. I want to test the significance of a certain value of the statistic but I obviously do not know the distribution of the statistic so I can't use t-test and such and I also have a sample of size 1000 from the population. I guess I could use non-parametric methods like bootstrapping and such to approximate the p-value of a certain statistic value but the research papers that I have been reading seem to use methods from Large Deviation Statistics and Fast Fourier Transforms. I have not have time to learn these concepts on my own and just need a nudge in the right direction. Any ideas ?

Comment: Bootstrap sounds good to me.

Comment: Any ideas on something faster and more precise ?